# Uipath excel import to Microsoft Access automation fails

Tags: excel, ms-access, rpa, uipath

I want to import the excel to Microsoft Access, and this process is automation, so I use double click to achieve it. Everything is fine until it stopped at one step which needs to click the `OK` button after import the xlsx file.

I don’t know why it stopped there, other double clicks are fine besides this.

[image: UiPath Studio]

And a video about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KI4hg_9zRVI

Comment: please mention the time stamp of that message box.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want to achieve the following.

- You have a spreadsheet of data
- This data needs importing into a database (MS Access)

One of the 'problems' with RPA/Automation is that we tend to automate actions rather than outcomes.

As a solution, rather than automating how a human would interact with MS Access and complete this task, think more about what you're trying to achieve.

At a very high level, you could do the following in your workflow, I've included links to UiPath documentation for each of the steps/activities.

1. Use read spreadsheet activities in UiPath to extract the data from your spreadsheet [excel-read-range](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/excel-read-range)
2. Parse/Validate/Filter the data you have just read [filter-data-table](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/filter-data-table)
3. Establish a database connection to the MS Access database [database-connect](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/database-connect) [UiPath forum example](https://forum.uipath.com/t/ms-access-database-connection/234823/3)
4. Perform a SQL query to insert the data from the spreadsheet into the database [execute-query](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/execute-query)